# Getting error while executing cmd git rebase -i master

Tags: git, vim

I am getting the following error while trying to rebase.

[image]

Tried googling didn't get much help.Kindly suggest if you have faced the issue.

Comment: Please don't post images in the code

Comment: You have chosen vim as your editor, and vim is not working correctly on your machine.  Why vim is not working correctly, I have no idea, but it is probably not related to git at all.

Comment: Here's a way to reconfigure an other editor for git on windows : https://github.com/blog/975-gitpad-write-your-commits-in-notepad